# Align element center below div (Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular, styling

My problem is, that I want to put a 'label' below my steps. But they have to be centered in relation to the circle with the number. I used position absolute for the labels. It should work for every amount of items (in this case 5).

[image]

Here is my code (Angular).

```css
.container {
        margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }

    .progresses{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .line{

        width: 20em;
        height: 6px;
        background: red; /* default color */

        /* "to left" / "to right" - affects initial color */
        background: linear-gradient(to left, dimgrey 50%, #63d19e 50%) right;
        background-size: 200%;
        transition: .5s ease-out;
    }

    .line.active{
        background-position: left;
    }


    .steps{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        transition: background-color 1s;
        background-color: dimgrey;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border-radius: 50%;

    }
    .steps.active{
        background-color: #63d19e;
    }
    .steps-footer {
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div *ngIf="items" class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

    <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" class="progresses">
        <div>
            <div class="steps"
                 [class.active]="!(currentItemIndex <= i)">
                <span *ngIf="currentItemIndex <= i" class="font-weight-bold">{{i + 1}}</span>
                <span *ngIf="currentItemIndex > i"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
            </div>
            <span class="steps-footer">{{item}}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="line"
              *ngIf="i !== items.length-1"
              [class.active]="!(currentItemIndex <= i)"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you put the circle and the label in one div, the circle gets pushed up and the circle doesnt align with the line anymore.

Comment: Could you provide a stackblitz reproducing your issue? It would make it easier for me to fix it, or else I would have to reproduce it myself. But basically what you want to do is put the step and the text inside the same div and then use flex to keep both of them centered.

Comment: Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wh8umr?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @JackTheRealPi Check this code: https://angular-ivy-5d8rzf.stackblitz.io

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I wanted. I mistakenly undone the upvote on your answer, and I can't upvote it anymore :( But much thanks @lukas